# Why the dtype changed differently after convert two lists with same type to numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, types

When I convert two lists of numpy arrays to numpy arrays of numpy arrays, something confused happened. 
The first list X_s changed to a numpy array with shape of (1980, 384, 448, 1), which is good for training, but the second list X_l chaned to a numpy arrays with shape of (2013,).
I check their dtype, and the first become float64 while the second become object of numpy array.
Why this happened?

```
print(len(X_s)) # 1980
print(len(X_l)) # 2013
print(X_s[0].dtype)  # float64
print(X_l[0].dtype)  # float64
print(X_s[0].shape)  # (384, 448, 1)
print(X_l[0].shape)  # (384, 448, 1)

for i in range(len(X_l)): 
    X_l[i] = np.array(X_l[i], dtype = np.float64)
for i in range(len(X_s)):
    X_s[i] = np.array(X_s[i], dtype = np.float64)

X_s = np.array(X_s)
X_l = np.array(X_l)

print(type(X_s[0]))  # <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(type(X_l[0]))  # <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

print(X_s.dtype) #  flaot64
print(X_l.dtype) #  object
print(X_s.shape) # （1980, 384, 448, 1）
print(X_l.shape) # （2013，）
```

After added two for loops to make sure the elements are in uniform type, nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

It looks very likely that the elements of the original `X_l` list are not of uniform type. (You only show us the type of the first element but not the rest.)

When NumPy tries to convert that list to an array, it notices that and coerces everything to `object`.

Demo:

```
In [10]: X_s = [np.array([1]), np.array([2])]

In [11]: X_l = [np.array([1]), 2]

In [12]: np.array(X_s)
Out[12]:
array([[1],
       [2]])

In [13]: np.array(X_l)
Out[13]: array([array([1]), 2], dtype=object)
```

(This example is made up but consistent with your observations.)

Comment: I used a loop  before the convert to make sure that the elements of the origin X_l list are in uniform type just now. But It didn't work.

Comment: After check the shape of every element in X_l, I found some element's shape is not (384, 448, 1).Thank you for your guidance.